# Why does changing the background color of the navigation bar in Cupertino App change the height?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget demonstrating the rendering of a Flutter app. As it's written below, the text is visible right underneath the `navigationBar`. However, if you comment out the `backgroundColor`, it becomes invisible. Why is that?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text("Settings"),
          previousPageTitle: "Back",
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text("Hello World!"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Without blue color: [image: Image without blue color]

With blue color: [image: Image with blue color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height is not changing with the `backgroundColor`, here's what [CupertinoPageScaffold's documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageScaffold/child.html) says:

> Content can slide under the navigationBar when they're translucent. In
> that case, the child's BuildContext's MediaQuery will have a top
> padding indicating the area of obstructing overlap from the
> navigationBar.

This is why your text is hidden, it's simply going under the bar when its color is translucent. By using `Colors.blue` you will have an opaque color.

You can try by using `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent` the result will be the same as putting no color.

To fix this behavior you can wrap your `Column` with a `SafeArea` widget:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        navigationBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(
          middle: Text("Settings"),
          previousPageTitle: "Back",
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text("Hello World!"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4748d7905fc5324a0e2628ae2c6e6784)

Answer (score 2):

@GuillaumeRoux has clarify the reason. You can fix it by [`SafeArea`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) if translucent color is required.

```dart
CupertinoApp(
  home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
    navigationBar: const CupertinoNavigationBar(
      middle: Text("Settings"),
      previousPageTitle: "Back",
    ),
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: const <Widget>[
          Text("Hello World!"),
        ],
      )
    ),
  ),
);
```